# Give out parent folder name if not containing a certain file

Tags: linux, terminal

I am looking for a terminal linux command to give out the folder parent name that does not contain a certain file:
By now I use the following command:

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}'/recon-all.done \; -print| wc -l
```

Which gives me the amount of folders which contain then file.

The file `recon-all.done` would be in `/subject/../../recon-all.done` and I would need every single "subject" name which does not contain the `recon-all.done` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the directories, test for the existence of the file, and print the directory if the test fails.

```
for subject in */; do
    if ! [ -e "${subject}scripts/recon-all.done" ]
    then echo "$subject"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Then I get all subfolders which does not contain the file, but I would only need the parent folder. The file recon-all.done is always in the following folder:

./subject/scripts/recon-all.done

Comment: That's not the same as your question. You don't need to use `find` if you know that it's always in the `scripts` subdirectory. Just check for `$subject/scripts/recon-all.done`

Answer (score 0):

Your command;

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}'/recon-all.done \; -print| wc -l
```

Almost does the job, we'll just need to

- Remove `| wc -l` to show the directory path **witch does not** contain the `recon-all` file
- Now, we can **negate** the `-exec test` by adding a `!` like so:

```sh
find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}'/recon-all.done \; -print
```

This way `find` will show each folder name if it **does not contain** the `recon-all` file

**Note**; Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439940/give-out-parent-folder-name-if-not-containing-a-certain-file/67440041#comment119202584_67440003) on Barmar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67440003/5625547), I've added a `-maxdepth 1` to prevent deeper directorys from being checked.

---

Small example from my local machine:

```
$ /tmp/test$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── test.xt
├── b
├── c
│   └── test.xt
└── x
    ├── a
    │   └── test.xt
    └── b

6 directories, 3 files
$ /tmp/test$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/test.xt' \; -print
.
./b
./x
$ /tmp/test$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Then I get all subfolders which does not contain the file, but I would only need the parent folder. The file recon-all.done is always in the following folder: ./subject/scripts/recon-all.done. And i only need the subject folder name. )The subject folder contains a lot of other folders)

Comment: Ahh, just to slow :) I've changed my answer just now to prevent this using `max-depth`, please see my example, it should match your case.